# What is the correct tool remove metal fence L-posts?

Tags: fence, post

The previous home owner hammered L and T- fence posts deep into the ground to support a make-shift retaining wall. They seem to be 6-feet in length and hammered within 6-inches of ground level. I have a farm jack and T-post puller, but I can’t figure out a method to attach anything to the pictured L-shaped posts. They have a series of holes which are about 3/16-inch diameter. Is there a commercial tool to facilitate removal of these posts?

[image]

Comment: Wrap a chain around it, cross the chain over and wrap again.  Use the jack.

Comment: Or bet some teens a 100 bucks if they can pull all out by hand.

Comment: Good idea! I’ve tried a chain a few times. It’s grips well, but give way and pops up the post before there is enough force to lift the post.

Comment: Can also try placing bolt/s in the holes to give the chain a better grip.

Comment: Drive them the rest of the way into the ground and call it a day? :)

Comment: This may be a little over the top suggestion (which is why it's not an answer), but if the area is accessible, you might consider renting a mini-excavator that has a bucket with a thumb.  Grab the post with the bucket, wiggle it side to side in both directions to loosen it, then try to lift it out. If that doesn't work, use the machine to dig around it, most have bits sticking out on regular spacing that could help hold a chain.   ...continued below...

Comment: The only other thing I could think of is to use large C-clamps over the chain over several wraps and use the jack.  Either that or go buy a truck with a winch, just make sure your life insurance is paid up!  (NOT a serious suggestion, just having fun).

Comment: I have used a T post puller to pull those out but wrapped a ratchet strap around the cable in a figure 8 then tightened , 4” or so the first couple of times then it was loose enough for just the cable that normally hooks on the notches on the T posts, the L brackets were smooth, after a dozen I wanted to speed up drilled a hole and used a gutter spike it was faster than the ratchet strap, after a couple pulls I could pull them out by hand. But the lever and cable T post puller really helped (yes my puller is home made) I have a cable setup and a steel z hook (the cable works best for deep ones

Comment: That ground looks quite dry.  If possible pouring water down so it soaks the ground will probably help.  Did any of the posts you pulled out look like the ground/dirt was damp below?

Comment: You could try a pressure washer and do a bit of pin-point hydro-excavation around them, if you have a pressure-washer handy. But I'd reach for putting a bolt in to catch the -t-post puller (depending on design) or chain. A cheap "lifting clamp" on top might also work, given it won't be falling on you if it fails (where you don't want a cheap one.)

Comment: Thanks! This is great advice. I’ll try to drill the holes larger, but I don’t have a drill bit capable of drilling this material handy.  The soil is actually very wet about 6-12 inches down. The soil is heavily rooted from nearby pine trees which makes digging around the posts difficult.

Answer (score 2):

Use the holes to bolt short t-post to the angle iron and then use your post puller on that.

Else a post puller with a c shaped claw might work for you.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First, assume that these stakes are just driven into the ground.   That means they have to back out the same path.

- put a stout bolt through the lowest hole you can access, then use a crowbar to lever that bolt straight out.  You'll need some blocking to spread the load and stop the crowbar/pinchbar from digging in.  If you don't have a bar, then a length of timber may work as a lever.  
   The ideal tool here is a high-lift jack but they're not common.
- bolt a chain to the top, with a shackle if you have one.  Use a stout garden fork or a spade as a pivot arm, and run the chain through the handle such that it is in-line with the stake.  Then run chain horizontally to a winch or fixed anchor point.  I'd use a hand-winch like a tirfor with a wire rope ideally, or a vehicle/trailer winch.  
  Last resort is to use a spanish windlass which is two long stakes in a cross such that rotating them hauls on the rope/wire/chain. 
   It may be possible to use a vehicle to pull the chain, but ultra-slowly because this stuff gets dangerous.

---

If someone has used extra reinforcing (like a footer of concrete, or horizontal bolts below ground level) then your best option is to dig out the first one with a shovel and spade and then reevaluate.

---

The worst option is to dig down a handsbredth and cut off the top with a cutoff wheel or hacksaw.  That leaves a sharp edge just below ground level, and someone, sometime in the future will find it risking injury.  Don't leave it there.   Same goes for hammering it flat or pounding it fully into the ground - this is poor stewardship of the site.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I’ll try some of these. I’m worried that a 3/16-inch bolt wouldn’t hold up to the force. For the T-posts (which I have a tool to attach to) tool the full capacity of my 5000lb jack.

Comment: @kvl good point - you can drill the hole out to something larger, and/or use a D shackle or Bow shackle that goes through and provides support on both sides.   No matter what, leverage is your friend here.

Comment: If you do happen to go with the vehicle idea, google 'spare tire stump removal'... (It's still not a great idea, imho -- you can see many fails on youtube.)